# How to install older gcc package using APT from a repository?

Tags: repository, gcc, add-apt-repository

I have GCC v9. But I'm trying to install a **GCC 4.8.1** version to test a library compilation on that very old version of GCC.

The version is not available in the official Ubuntu repos,it is deprecated, but I've found it in other mirrors as told by the official GCC website. This one seems like popular one:

[https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test)

I have very little knowledge of linux package systems except for the basic. I want to keep both versions. So I should do this:

```
sudo apt -y install gcc-4.8.1 gcc-9
```

The reason why I want to use this command and not install it from the file, apart from the difficulty of doing that for me, is that I'm following a guide in order to have several GCCs on my system:
https://www.fosslinux.com/39386/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-gcc-and-g-on-ubuntu-20-04.htm

When I add the url to the sources.list file seems like it is working.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update -q
```

But when I try to call the install with gcc-4.8.1 or gcc-4.8 , or even gcc-4 the package doesn't exist.

> Package gcc-4.8 is not available, but is referred to by another
> package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
> obsoleted, or is only available from another source E: Package
> 'gcc-4.8' has no installation candidate

Also, I don't know if websites like these can be added to the repos list in order to find the package using APT:

http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.1/

[EDIT]

I downloaded the package from the website I linked. I have no idea how to install this by hand. If only I could find a repository that could help me with this... I have no idea how to make APT help me with the installation.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your release, but is it supported by https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test as that PPA doesn't support all releases  (also note 4.8 is only provided for some older and mostly EOL releases, refer the link you provided!)

Comment: @guiverc Isn't that the same link I put in my post? My question is basically how do you add one of those websites so that APT gets packages from them. Those are not repositories, are they?. I just have no idea how to add anything in the repos list, if it's a mirror like those.

Comment: PPA's are 3rd party repositories, but they don't support all releases. You haven't mentioned your release, so my point was you'll have to use that link to check it supports your *unstated* release given you haven't told us & we can't help you without that detail. We need to know your OS & release details to help further.

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 64 bit.  Gnome version 3.36.8     Thanks!

Comment: That PPA provides no support for *focal* (or 20.04), the front page tells you that if you look. The message "*Package gcc-4.8 is not available*" is what you'd expect, it's available for other releases yes, and that PPA provides gcc-10 for *groovy* etc, but provide no packages for *focal*.  3rd party sources (PPAs) are all on you to check (are they maintained, suitable, trustworthy, etc)